# Removing a outer array from JSON object - PHP

Tags: php, json

I have fetched Google Analytics profiles from my account, and returned an JSON object to my view. But I want to convert this object.

```
[
    {
        Account A: {
            xxxxxxxx: "All Web Site Data"
        }
    },
    {
        Account B: {
            xxxxxxxx: "All Web Site Data"
        }
    }
]
```

to this

```
{
    Account A: {
        xxxxxxxx: "All Web Site Data"
    }
},
{
    Account B: {
        xxxxxxxx: "All Web Site Data"
    }
}
```

How can i do this using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Your json object looking incorrect, try this way

```
<?php 

$jsond = '[{ "AccountA": {"xxxxxxxx": "All Web Site Data"}},{"AccountB": {"xxxxxxxx": "All Web Site Data"}}]';
$arr = json_decode(trim($jsond));
//echo json_last_error_msg ();
print_r($arr[0]);
?>
```

Simply use `[0]` index object

### JavaScript

```
var json = json[0];
console.log(json);
```

### PHP

```
var $json = $json[0];
var_dump($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$json = (array) json_decode($yourJson);
var_dump($json);
```